# Checking Valid Arithmetic Expression in Lex (in C)

Tags: c, regex, validation, lex

I have to write code for checking if an arithmetic expression is valid or not , in lex. I am aware that I could do this very easily using yacc but doing only in lex is not so easy.

I have written the code below, which for some reason doesn't work.
Besides this, i also don't get how to handle binary operators .

**My wrong code:**

```flex
%{
#include <stdio.h>
/* Will be using stack to check the validity of arithetic expressions */
char stack[100];
int top = 0;
int validity =0;S
%}
operand [a-zA-Z0-9_]+

%%
  /* Will consider unary operators (++,--), binary operators(+,-,*,/,^), braces((,)) and assignment operators (=,+=,-=,*=,^=) */
"("                { stack[top++]='(';}
")"                { if(stack[top]!=')') yerror(); else top--;}
[+|"-"|*|/|^|%]    { if(stack[top]!='$') yerror(); else stack[top]=='&';}
"++"          { if(stack[top]!='$') yerror(); else top--;}
[+"-"*^%]?=        { if(top) yerror();}
operand            { if(stack[top]=='&') top--; else stack[top++]='$';}

%%

int yerror()
{
    printf("Invalid Arithmetic Expression\n");
}
```

Comment: @iharob Could you suggest what should I do here ? It seems taking care of both unary and binary operators is difficult.

Comment: Why aren't you using `bison`? That way it's much easier to write the parser.

Comment: @iharob Yup, I understand, flex and bison are made for each other, but I am constrained only to do it in lex.

Comment: Why are you trying to jam a parser into lexer's actions?

Comment: @n.m. I have to. This is the task.Please help.

Comment: You didn't say you need to put all C code into actions. Is this an explicit reqirement in your assignment? Can you post the assignment verbatim?

Comment: no it is not the requirement.

Comment: The character class `[+|"-"|*|/|^|%]` doesn't do what you think it does.  It should be written either `+|"-"|*|/|^|%` or `[-+*/^%]`.  As it stands, both pipe and quote are also operators.  You probably need a rule to recognize numbers rather than identifiers, at least to start with.  Add variables after you've got basic arithmetic on numbers working.

Comment: The stray `S` in `int validity =0;S` is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|^|%` would be the minimal quotation necessary, I think.

Comment: OK so the normal and acceptable course of actions is to write a normal (recursive-descent or other) parser in C and use a lexer written in lex with it. That's what I would do if I was told to use only lex and C. Obviously it's not possible in lex alone.

Comment: @n.m.: You can use a start condition stack if you want a simple recursive lexer. I agree that it's not ideal, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: @rici I think it's flex-specific, not a feature of the regular lex. And you need to write some C code anyway.

Comment: @n.m.: OK, good point. It is flex-specific; without flex, you'd need an explicit stack (as in OP). You will always need to write *some* C code, if only to avoid echoing everything; you couldn't hook the lexer up to a parser without at least enough C code to return tokens.

Comment: @rici: yes, now you mention it, it would take more quoting than I gave, but the concept is still correct.  Either it needs to be a character class, or it needs to be an alternation; it should not try to mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn how to write regular expressions in Flex. ([Patterns, Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)).

Inside a character class (`[`…`]`), neither quotes nor stars nor vertical bars are special. To include a <kbd>-</kbd> or a <kbd>]</kbd>, you can escape them with a <kbd>\</kbd> or put them at the beginning of the list, or in the case of <kbd>-</kbd> at the end.

So in:

```
[+|"-"|*|/|^|%]
```

The <kbd>|</kbd> is just another character in the list, and including it five times doesn't change anything. `"-"` is a character range consisting only of the character <kbd>"</kbd>, although I suppose the intention was to include a <kbd>-</kbd>. Probably you wanted `[-+*/^%]` or `[+\-*/^%]`.

There is no way that the flex scanner can guess that a <kbd>+</kbd> (for example) is a unary operator instead of a binary operator, and putting it twice in the list of rules won't do anything; the first rule will always take effect.

Finally, if you use definitions (like `operand`) in your patterns, you have to enclose them in braces: `{operand}`; otherwise, flex will interpret it as a simple keyword.

And a hint for the assignment itself: A valid unparenthesized arithmetic expression can be simplified into the regular expression:

```
term    {prefix-operator}*{operand}{postfix-operator}*
expr    {term}({infix-operator}{term})*
```

But you can't use that directly because (a) it doesn't deal with parentheses, (b) you probably need to allow whitespace, and (c) it doesn't correctly reject `a+++++b` because C insists on the "maximal munch" rule for lexical scans, so that is not the same as the correct expression `a++ + ++b`.

You can, however, translate the above regular expression into a very simple two-state state machine.